# Android: Merging JSON and HashMap data

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist, hashmap

I've JSON data from facebook:

```
String response = facebook.request("me/friends?fields=username",bundle,"GET");
```

And data from the user's contacts:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data = getContacts();
```

I'm looking to iterate through both `response` and `data`. How could this be done most efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you read this great tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html

Although I prefer to use the Jackson library. Here is a tutorial:

http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes

If you know Spanish in androcode.es can find some tutorials about JSON written by me.